# How do I install OpenCV on Windows Azure?

Tags: opencv, azure, video-streaming, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I am a beginner with Windows Azure and I want to make an app which does facial recognition on a video stream. Hence I need to install OpenCV (C++ Library).
How do I do that? And how do I get the video stream from the client app? (I am in control of the client app as well).

Comment: did this need startup tasks or did you just import it into the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library simply needs to be on the path for your application to pick it up, then just add it as an item in the project you're deploying, and it will get uploaded up to Azure, and deployed alongside your application.

If some commands are required to install it, you can use [startup tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx).

As for the video stream, you can open a socket (using a TCP endpoint) and stream the video up to an azure instance that way. That's probably the most efficient way of doing it if you want real time video processing. If you want to record the video and upload it, look at using [blob storage](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/storage/). You can then use a message queue to signal to the worker, that there is a video waiting to be processed.

Comment: How do I stream video from Client to Server via Sockets?